# Gap between textbox and a button in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, search

i create search bar in .aspx
code

```
   <div align ="center"     
        style="border: thick none #008080; height: 597px; width: 670px; color: #000000; font-weight: bold; font-size: medium; font-family: Calibri;"><br /><br />        
        <center><div class="vpb_main_wrapper3" top="20" align="center" style="left: inherit"/><br clear="all"/>
        <h1 align="center" 

                style="color: #3399FF; font-weight: bolder; font-size: xx-large; font-family: 'Footlight MT Light';">
         ALL DOCUMENTS</h1><hr /><hr /><hr /><br /><br />
              <div>
          <asp:TextBox ID="searz" runat="server"  class="searches" type="text" CausesValidation="false"  placeholder="Search Documents"></asp:TextBox>
<%--     <input id="searz" class="searches" runat="server" type="text" CausesValidation="false"  placeholder="Type here"/>
--%>   <button id="submits" class="submit" runat="server"  type="submit"  onserverclick="Btn_submits_Click" CausesValidation="false" value="Search" validationgroup="123">Search</button>

    </div>

                <div class="CSSTableGenerator">
                <table border="0" width="100%" ..........
```

and here is output..
[image: [pic]

it looks like there is so many gap between textbox and a button so how i remove gap between textbox and button

can any one suggest how i solve this?
thankx

Answer (score 0):

i solve this by removing this ....

```
.searches, #submit
{
    float:left;
}
```